# Android change drawable solid color programmatically

Tags: android, colors, drawable

I have a drawable that is an oval shape with a with check mark inside.
Is it possible to change the oval color programmatically without changing the check mark color ?

Here's my drawable:

```
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/check_mark"/>
</item>
```

What I would like to do is only change the solid black color to something else programmatically

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to just add a second drawables with other "oval"-color and then replace the drawable programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can grammatically create a shape using below reference code.

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.setCornerRadius(24);
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
shape.setColor(R.color.red);
imageView.setBackground(shape);
```

Answer (score 0):

The drawable is an oval and is the background of an ImageView

Get the Drawable from imageView using getBackground():

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
```

Check against usual suspects:

```
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    // cast to 'ShapeDrawable'
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = (ShapeDrawable) background;
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    // cast to 'GradientDrawable'
    GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) background;
    gradientDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    // alpha value may need to be set again after this call
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
    colorDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
}
```

Compact version:

```
Drawable background = imageView.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
    ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
    ((GradientDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
} else if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
    ((ColorDrawable)background).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.colorToSet));
}
```